# Convert timestamp to postgres timestamp

Tags: python, postgresql, timestamp

Currently i have the following timestamp format as below :

```
2018-04-02T09:00:00+09:30
```

How can i convert the timestamp above to suit the postgres's timestamp column like below?

```
2018-04-02 09:00:00 +09.30
```

Also how can use python to convert the xml timestamp first before loading into postgres table?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't require any conversion whatsoever, it's a regular [ISO 8601 time stamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). [PostgreSQL supports multiple input formats for time stamps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-INPUT)

```
select timestamp with time zone '2018-04-02T09:00:00+09:30';
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2018-04-01 18:30:00-05
(1 row)
```

You'll notice it's storing it in UTC. That's what you want. From [the docs,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)

> **For `timestamp with time zone`, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time**, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is **converted to UTC** using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's `TimeZone` parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.
>
> When a `timestamp with time zone value` is output, it is always **converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as local time in that zone.** To see the time in another time zone, either change timezone or use the `AT TIME ZONE` construct (see Section 9.9.3).

Comment: Can i choose not store to utc? just store it as it is **'2018-04-02 09:00:00 +09:30'** like this? This timestamp is already converted from UTC

Comment: @Derek You don't ever store timestamps in anything *other* than UTC. All timestamps are normalized to UTC. Then they get displayed in whatever timestamp you want in the application (assuming the column type is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`). For instance, in `psql` you can set the time zone you want your time stamp dipslayed in with `TimeZone` configuration variable.

Comment: thanks for your advice! however, i can't store it into utc format as I already have a column which stores utc format. Therefore, I need to store this timestamp as it is without timezone

Comment: @Derek ask questions, because you're not understanding something. (or read the docs above).

Answer (score 0):

If you know you will always get your data in that format, you can do something like:

```
>>> a = "2018-04-02T09:00:00+09:30"
>>> 
>>> b = a.replace('T', ' ').replace('+', ' +')
>>> b
'2018-04-02 09:00:00 +09:30'
```

It is ugly, but it works.

It is always safer to interpret your input as a date and then print it in the desired format.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! can you briefly explain what .replace('+', ' +') does?

Comment: It replaces '+' with ' +', adding an extra "space" before '+'.